# java encryption redux

Tags: java, char

I with my beginner skils in Java, can't figure out how to encrypt text. Yes I do know that there are alot of libraries and APIS, but this time I want to do this ny way so I understand everything perfectly.

So my idea and question is how to assign values to characters and later use them (encrypt and decrypt). For example A = 12; B = 13; C = 14; D = 15. So DBAC would be 15131214

So far I made this program that just increases character by one, but I cant figure out how to assign diferent values.

```
package javaapplication2;

public class JavaApplication2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int b;
    String text = "criptable text";
    char[] textArray = text.toCharArray();

    for(int index=0; index < textArray.length;index++){
        textArray[index]++;

    }

    String done = new String (textArray);
    System.out.println(done);
}
}
```

Comment: There is no encryption in evidence here at all. What is your question?

Comment: okay, sry sor my low PC and programming skils. I am just beginnig with all PC and coding. But this says all - For example A = 12; B = 13; C = 14; D = 15. So DBAC would be 15131214 I want to type in sentence that will be changed to my predefined values

Comment: For the record: Your idea is called a [substitution cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher). And a really bad one at that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for something like this?

```
public class TestType {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    /*
     * Create a Map of replacements
     */
    Map<Character, String> keyMap = new HashMap<Character, String>();
    keyMap.put('a', "12");  keyMap.put('b', "13");
    keyMap.put('c', "14");  keyMap.put('d', "15");
    keyMap.put('e', "16");  keyMap.put('f', "17");
    keyMap.put('g', "18");  keyMap.put('h', "19");
    //Add more key-values for all letter support


    String plainText = "abcdefgh";
    StringBuffer encrypted = new StringBuffer();

    for (char ch : plainText.toCharArray()) {
        /* Form the encrypted string */
        encrypted.append(keyMap.get(ch));

    }

    System.out.println("Encrypted: " + encrypted.toString());

}
```

}

Comment: wow, this is really nice and easy to understand. Thanks

Comment: and any ideas how to get normal text from changed values, because seems that if you have changed char to two digits it is not possible to use string to charr any more.

Comment: you know its 2 digits!.. just split and reconstruct

Answer (score 1):

A very simple approach might be to have a `hashmap` key value pair, with key being alphabets and value being any number you want to assign.

Then in the function, get character from array, and assign it a value by looking up in `hashmap`

Answer (score 1):

In order to have different values (and not only increment) you need a dictionary which holds the information of the value for each letter.

By the way you are trying to do something similar to the Caesar cipher (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher).

Comment: Yes, thank you thats the thing i wanted to make, but the Question is how, I cant figure it out

Comment: Both mkhelif and Zohaib just *told* you how.  Your mission is: 1) Google for "java hashmap" or "java dictionary", 2) Write a small test case that uses a hashmap (e.g. map "A" to the number "12"), and finally 3) apply what you've learned to your program :)